# How to add value to specific index that is out of bounds

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a list array

```
list = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]
```

Say I add [6, 7, 8] to the first row as the header for my three new columns, what's the best way to add values in these new columns, without getting index out of bounds? I've tried first filling all three columns with "" but when I add a value, it then pushes the "" out to the right and increases my list size.

Would it be any easier to use a Pandas dataframe? Are you allowed "gaps" in a Pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

according to ops comment i think a pandas df is the more appropriate solution. you can not have 'gaps', but nan values like this

```
import pandas as pd

# create sample data
a = np.arange(1, 6)
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(*[a]*5))

print(df)
```

output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0  1  1  1  1  1
1  2  2  2  2  2
2  3  3  3  3  3
3  4  4  4  4  4
4  5  5  5  5  5
```

for adding empty columns:

```
# add new columns, not empty but filled w/ nan
df[5] = df[6] = df[7] = float('nan')

# fill single value in column 7, index 3
df[7].iloc[4] = 123

print(df)
```

output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4   5   6      7
0  1  1  1  1  1 NaN NaN    NaN
1  2  2  2  2  2 NaN NaN    NaN
2  3  3  3  3  3 NaN NaN    NaN
3  4  4  4  4  4 NaN NaN    NaN
4  5  5  5  5  5 NaN NaN  123.0
```

Comment: thank you, but how do I add value to let's say row 3, index 8 without filling in indexes 0-7?

Comment: you'd have to fill those columns with placeholders, e.g. nan. but I think a pandas solution is easier. see the edited answer